# SLIM template in Rails: How to render html element from instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml, slim-lang

- ruby 1.9.2p290
- rails 3.1.1

How to create a html element from controller in **SLIM** templates?

I will explain:

In my views, I want to change the "h1" html tag by some conditions.

**But I want to put the logic inside controller.**

```
case params[:controller] when "recipes", "chefs"
    case params[:action] when "show", "index"
      @h_number = "h2"
    else
      @h_number ="h1"
    end
  else
    @h_number ="h1"
end
```

In my **SLIM** view, I would like something like that:

```
= @h_number#logo
    = link_to image_tag("image.png"), root_path
```

Which results in:

```
<h1 id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="image.png"></a></h2>
```

or

```
<h2 id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="image.png"></a></h2>
```

Is it possible?

Am I clear? Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt this is possible. But you could always create a helper method to do this

In your application helper file,

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def logo
        num = case params[:controller] when "recipes", "chefs"
          case params[:action] when "show", "index" then 2 end
        end || 1

        "<h#{num}>" + link_to(image_tag("image.png"), root_path) + "</h#{num}>"
    end
end
```

In your template

```
body
  header
    == logo
```

And your controllers don't need anything.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new on rails! Your answer is perfect for me.

Comment: It's a old thread but i think it's worth to mention for those like me that are starting. The double equals sign (`==`) produces the output without the `escape_html ` method.